# unable to reset password for postgres user in postgresql 8.4 windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, postgresql, postgres-8.4

How to change password of postgres user in windows server 2012 r2, I tried change md5 to trust in pg_hba.conf file & restart postgres services but still it asks password while connecting from command line or console.

screenshots

[image: pg_hba.conf] & [image: pgAdm-console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 9.0 FAQ http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#I_lost_the_database_password._What_can_I_do_to_recover_it.3F

**I lost the database password. What can I do to recover it?**

You can't. However, you can reset it to something else. To do this, you

1. Edit pg_hba.conf to allow trust authorization temporarily
2. Reload the config file (pg_ctl reload)
3. Connect and issue ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'newpassword';
   to set the new password (for first time users note the semi-colon)
4. Edit pg_hba.conf again and restore the previous settings Reload the
   config file again

Comment: Fantabulous.... :) Did Worked indeed... Thanks ton.

Reload the config file (pg_ctl reload) means 

D:\postgres8.4\bin>pg_ctl.exe F:\postgres8.4\data\